# Does the presence of an "unsafe" function in an object file pose a security risk

Tags: vulnerability, c, programming, c++

I've read that there are unsafe functions that we should try to avoid when writing C/C++ programs for example the `gets()` or `strlen()` functions.

Let's say I compile a .cpp/.c file into an object file and then I run the following command (suppose I'm using Linux):

```
objdump -t <objec_file_name>.o | grep "strlen"
```

and it shows in the symbol table that `strlen` is there.

Output example:

```
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 strlen
```

but in my .c/.cpp file I do not use `strlen` or in any other files that are included by a `#include "some_file_ive_created.h"` directive (I've seen this happen before). My question is this something that hacker could take advantage of or are there any other security risks that are associated with having an unsafe function in the object file only but not in any source file.

Answer (score 2):

"Unsafe" functions like `strlen` are not a security risk due to their pure existence. They are also not a risk in an arbitrary context. But it is easy for programmers to not be aware of the limits of these functions and thus use these in an insecure way (in case of strlen: using it with a character buffer which is not guaranteed to contain a `\0` inside, thus risking overflow). That's why they are considered unsafe and there are safe alternatives offered (like `strnlen`, which gives a maximum length to scan)

Therefore it is only a security risk if the function is a) actually used and b) in an insecure way.
It is not a risk if the function is inside the binary but not used.

Comment: would you know if just the pure existence of an unsafe function could help somebody reverse engineer a binary more easily ?

Comment: @Simon: I don't think this would help. Also, if you link the objects to a static binary then any unused functions should not be in the final binary.